# Book recommendations for beginners about probability distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, references

I'm studying machine learning and every book I open I bump into chi-squared distribution, gamma-function, t-distribution, Gaussian, etc.

Every book I have opened so far only defines what the distributions are: they don't explain or give the intuition on where the specific formulas for the functions come from.

For example, why is chi-squared distribution the way it is? What is the t-distribution? What is the intuition behind the distribution? Proofs? etc.

I would like to have a clear and fundamental understanding of the most commonly used distributions so that every time later on when I see them, I truly understand what is a t-distribution, what is a Gaussian distribution and most importantly why are they the way they are.

It would be nice if the books / tutorials can explain the concepts to a layman so that in order to understand them you don't already need to understand them x) Many books are like this, they don't fit for beginners

Comment: While this is the go-to reference book: [Continuous Univariate Distributions](https://www.amazon.com/Continuous-Univariate-Distributions-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471584959) by Johnson, Kotz, for your purpose, any general undergrad stats books like Casella, Berger; Rohatgi will be suffice for they provide sufficient treatment in explaining the common distributions that are frequent in the studies.

Comment: Generally one studies probability theory before studying statistics/machine learning.

Comment: @utobi That doesn't mean it's the best approach.  A couple decades ago I taught an intermediate level course on prob & stats that developed the probability only when it was needed to address statistical problems.  Based on pre- and post-testing results, this course was much more successful for learning statistics than the traditional method.

Comment: I have already checked Kotz distributions book series, I could not find what I want in those books.

Comment: I want to know how and why particular mathematicians came up with those distribution forms, what ateps they followed etc. No matter how deep math there is in those books I am eager to explore. My question was fully copy pasted from one post in 2013. Actually, I am an actuary and somehow this distributions thing makes me frustrated. Please, guide me to find those materials

Comment: @whuber I agree with you (+1) but I would say that it also depends on the target. For instance, in my university, many statistics courses for non-statisticians/non-mathematicians (e.g., economics, engineering, etc.) are typically taught that way (i.e. prob as much as needed during the stat course).

Comment: In every case I can think of, most well-known distributional forms arose well before anyone considered using them to describe probability distributions.  The earliest distributions employed were the Binomial (in use by 1654) and Normal (c. 1730), but I know the former appeared in combinatorics earlier (in the 1640's) and suspect the latter arose in studies of diffusion processes by c. 1700. Ultimately, many common distributions are connected through natural test statistics for Normal variables: Student *t*, $\chi^2$ (= Gamma), and F ratio.

Comment: @utobi The one I taught was a course for prospective math and statistics majors.

Comment: @whuber incredible! I am too curious, I wish I can have a look at these notes...

Comment: @utobi I was going to say there aren't many notes, but I checked and I would be wrong. I have records of my plans for each week of class; lab notes; many references to books and papers; and 140 pages of responses to student questions ("FAQs").  Students were required to write at least one thoughtful question on an "exit card" before leaving each class meeting.  I collected those questions and provided extensive answers in the next meeting.  These were good students, so the FAQs cover a lot of material -- far more than the few chapters of the textbook we made it through.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with any book that would meet your requirements, but there's a Harvard course [Statistics 110](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home) by Joe Blitzstein that focuses exactly on the intuitions behind the distributions and probability theory concepts. (It is freely available online.)

Answer (score 1):

Blitzstein & Hwang's ["Introduction to Probability"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138369918) is in the same vein as the online course referenced by Tim but a lot more breadth. Highly recommended.